# How to get Linux command location in C?

Tags: c, linux, command-line, command

I am using `execv` in C, but it demands to get the path of the command to get it executed, For example:

- To execute `ls` I must have `char* command = "/bin/ls";`
- To execute `gedit` I must have char* `command = "/usr/bin/gedit";`

My question is how to get the string `"/bin"` or `"/usr/bin"` in C ?

Comment: Use `execvp()` instead?  It searches in the directories in the PATH to try to find the commands.  Or you can simulate it, but that's harder.

Comment: It's working, but I want to know a way to get the command location. Thanks :)

Comment: Go through each path in the `PATH` environment variable, and search each folder for the wanted file.

Comment: Step through each of the directories listed in PATH in turn and see whether the file is present and executable by the user.  That's doable, but dealing with complexities like ACLs for permissions is tricky — something you shouldn't bother with on a first pass, but which you might need to futz with later.  Or maybe you wouldn't; I've not had to do so yet, though the day may come.

Comment: Incidentally, the fact that there isn't a standard library function to do this indicates that it isn't often needed in practice — or that everybody has written their own variant and there's no single interface that dominates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the PATH variable from the environment. Then you parse it to get each component, then check in the location of each component whether the given command (file) exists there.

This is basically what the `which` command does. Source code of linux utilities can be found on-line

Answer (score 3):

which command gives the complete path of a command. For example,

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

So, you can do something like this in a C program,

```
system ("which ls >x");
// read file x for complete path of ls
```

Comment: Note: the `x` will be a file in the current directory and the code will need to open, read, close that file to get the actual results of the `which` command